# MongoDB - How to retrieve only one specific document from a collection

Tags: database, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongo-collection

I have created a database called "Cars" and a collection inside it as, "Cars_info". I have inserted 8 documents inside it as follows.

```
db.Cars_info.insertMany([
  { car_id: "c1", Company: "Toyota", Model: "Aqua", Year: 2020, Price_in_usd: 25000, Category: "High-end", Country: "Japan" },
  { car_id: "c2", Company: "Toyota", Model: "Premio", Year: 2019, Price_in_usd: 35000, Category: "High-end", Country: "Japan" },
  { car_id: "c3", Company: "Audi", Model: "A6", Year: 2020, Price_in_usd: 55000, Category: "High-end", Country: "Germany" },
  { car_id: "c4", Company: "Tata", Model: "Nano", Year: 2015, Price_in_usd: 10000, Category: "Low-end", Country: "India" },
  { car_id: "c5", Company: "Volkswagen", Model: "Taos", Year: 2022, Price_in_usd: 35000, Category: "High-end", Country: "Germany" },
  { car_id: "c6", Company: "Ford", Model: "Figo", Year: 2019, Price_in_usd: 26000, Category: "High-end", Country: "America" },
  { car_id: "c7", Company: "Mahindra", Model: "Thar", Year: 2018, Price_in_usd: 18000, Category: "Low-end", Country: "India" },
  { car_id: "c8", Company: "Honda", Model: "Vezel", Year: 2015, Price_in_usd: 33000, Category: "High-end", Country: "Japan" }
])
```

Here I want to retrieve only the third document from the collection. But without matching any field value. like,

```
db.Cars_info.find({"car_id":"c3"}).pretty()
```

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Try `db.Cars_info.findOne()`

Comment: @Wernfried Domscheit it retrieves the first document

Comment: What do you mean by "third document"? By default the documents in a collection do not have any order. Query `db.Cars_info.find().skip(2).limit(1)` returns an "arbitrary third" document, there is no guaranty that it will be `{car_id: "c3", ...}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [`.skip()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.skip/) and [`.limit()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.limit/).

Take the document by starting index: 2 and with only 1 document, which is the third document.

**Update**: Thanks and credit to @Wernfried for pointing out, you need [`.sort()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.sort/#mongodb-method-cursor.sort) to guarantee to get the nth of the document. For your scenario, you have to sort by `car_id`.

[Sort Consistency](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.sort/#std-label-sort-cursor-consistent-sorting)

> MongoDB does not store documents in a collection in a particular order. When sorting on a field that contains duplicate values, documents containing those values may be returned in any order.

```
db.Cars_info.find()
  .sort({ "car_id": 1 })
  .skip(2)
  .limit(1)
```

[image]

Comment: There is no order of documents. When you get correct document `{car_id: "c3", Company: "Audi", Model: "A6", Year: 2020, Price_in_usd: 55000, Category: "High-end", Country: "Germany"}` then it's just coincidence.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out, `.sort()` is a must to guarantee the order.